Symmetrized Bone Issues
Symmetrized the left-side bones. Right bones are labeled with _r. On the right side, the Bicep_Main_r mesh has been assigned to the respective _r bones, but when rotating or transforming them, they deform as so:

Another issue is that these bones should be on the right side (but are in the correct position in Edit Mode):

Lastly, rotating the left side mirrors the rotation to the right:



As you can see if you select one of these vertices, they should only be part of the vertex group called Bicep_connector_bone_r but they are also assigned to Bicep_connector_bone_l:

To remove them from this vertex group, select all these parts with L and remove from the vertex group:

For the small bones it has to do with the constraints you've given, I'm not sure how you want to make them work but the values of the Transformation constraints are very high and make the bones go away, and the Clamp To constraints make them stick to another object.
As for the third question, same as the first one, the vertices of the arms are not assigned to the correct vertex groups.
